# Label Text Changes During Code but Won't Say Changed

Tags: vb.net, label

I have code in my program that updates a database.  When the database has been updated, I change the text of a label to say "Last Update" and then the actual time when the update occurred.  This part works perfectly.

My problem occurs when I close the program and re-open it.  I want to code to check the date in the label and if the date in the label is less than the current date I want to update my database.  But when I close my program and re-open it the label in the text doesn't stay.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Screen_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim Time_of_Update = CDate(Label_Time_of_Update.Text.Split(" "c)(2).Trim())
    Debug.WriteLine(Time_of_Update)
    If Time_of_Update < Today Then
        Update_Data()
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Data()
    Update_Daily()
    Ready_Update_Quarterly_and_Annualy()

    Dim Time_of_Update = DateTime.Now
    Label_Time_of_Update.Text = "Last Updated " & Time_of_Update & ""
End Sub
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to save the LastUpdatedDate somewhere such as an App Setting

Comment: @Plutonix How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings in Project properties and create a `LastUpdatedDate` setting:

- `Name` == "LastUpdatedDate" basically a variable name
- `Type` == Date
- `Scope` == User (Application scope makes them Read Only)
- `Value` == a valid date

This defines the setting name and data type.  in code:

```
Dim Time_of_Update = DateTime.Now
Label_Time_of_Update.Text = "Last Updated " & Time_of_Update & ""

My.Settings.LastUpdatedDate = Time_of_Update
My.Settings.Save
```

next time you run:

```
Label_Time_of_Update.Text = My.Settings.LastUpdatedDate
```

Saving it as a `DateTime` type will make it easy to date comparison in code rather than converting it back from a String.

Comment: You may want to describe how to create the app setting prior to using this code.